# Which information is saved in an MS Edge profile that is persisted even after clearing cache and could disturb authentication?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

We have a business-system that queries multiple apis from different servers in our Windows domain through javascript calls. These calls are authenticated with the current windows identity. It usually works fine, but sometimes something breaks (we haven't figured out yet when/why it happens) and the service reports http 401 errors. If that happens even clearing the cache won't solve the problem, but a co-worker discovered that deleting the edge profile works (edge://settings/profiles).

So the question is, what is saved in the edge-profile, that could break windows auth? And even better, how to fix it?

Example for service-call:

```
function callService() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: apiConfig.appName,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (result) {
      resolve(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
    $("#errorPopUp").html(errorText);
  }
```

});
});

Any insight would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be related with [Sign in automatically using saved passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-identity#sign-in-automatically-using-saved-passwords) and [Single sign-on across work or school sites](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/08/21/sign-in-sync-work-school-accounts-aad-websso/).

> If a user saves passwords in Microsoft Edge, they can enable a feature that automatically logs them into websites where they have saved credentials.

> Once you’ve signed in to your organizational account in Microsoft Edge, we’ll use those credentials to authenticate you to websites and services that support Web Single Sign-On.

You can navigate to *edge://settings/passwords* to check if there's any saved passwords and navigate to *edge://settings/profiles/multiProfileSettings* to check if you have enabled **Allow single sign-on for work or school sites using this profile**. These data can't be cleared by clearing the cache. You can check if they're related with your authentication issue.

Comment: The second option is enabled in our domain, so there may be the issue. We'll check for saved passwords as soon as the next user calls and report back. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to help. You can come back any time after you check again.

Comment: No saved passwords on our last caller :( also just a single profile, so profile switching should not be the problem either

Comment: Do you mean the issue doesn't relate with Edge profile? Have you tested in other browsers like Chrome or Firefox to check if the issue persists?

Comment: The issue does not happen right from the start, just after some time. Earliest reports were two weeks after the app release. We tried different browsers and they work (without SSO though), but we haven't tried over some time (because missing sso sucks if you call services from 3 different machines)

Comment: It's strange that it happens sometimes. I think it might be related with single sign-on setting  in Edge, as without sso it works well in other browsers. You can disable *Allow single sign-on for work or school sites using this profile* in Edge, disable all the extensions, clear [All time browser data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXqXt.png) and test again. If it still doesn't work, I suggest that you can open a support ticket about this issue from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/support/).